# mercurial hg up -C created a branch with the same name as current, how to remove it or merge it

Tags: mercurial

I had a change in my branch and after unseccessfull merge, I tried to revert that unsuccessefull merge with `hg up -c` but it created a new branch instead. I can merge it into current or discard it or what to do with it?

**EDIT:**
actually I did the following, I had a branch and committed changes there there. then I wanted to push my changes to server, so I pulled changes, and tried to merge with them, but there were a conflict I couldn't resolve myself and I thought: I'll revert all changes back and merge again - so used `hg up -C` which I thought, will revert everything I changed during my unfinished merge. But what actually happened, another branch with the same name was created, containing only that changes I committed previously and with the same name as a branch I was working in and I was switched to the branch where I was working, which didn't have my changes. So two questions here: what actually happened and why another branch with the same name was created?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking since Mercurial doesn't do what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple heads on the same branch, which I think is what you're saying with "a branch with the same name as current" is a normal situation and, yes, you can use `hg merge` to consolidate them into one head.  Use the `hg heads` command to find the hashes of the two heads of branch X.  Then:

```
hg update REVISION_ID_OF_ONE_HEAD   # changes your working directory to match one of the heads
hg merge  REVISION_ID_OF_THE_OTHER_HEAD   # merges that head's changes in
hg commit      # create a new changeset that is the child of both those heads thus reducing the head count by one
```

Also @ringding is correct that `hg update` never creates branches.  You either already had them and didn't know or received another head when you pulled.

Comment: and your expanded text shows I was right in my guesses.  It wasn't the 'update' or the 'merge' that created the "2nd branch with the same name".  It was the 'pull' they do that.  You just need to do the merge and that means resolving the conflicts.  _update does not create branches_